# Remove certain text strings from a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To go along with the same area of my website, I'm wondering if there is a way to remove certain strings inside a paragraph, but not the entire paragraph. For some of the photo captions, it says `Photo Title (by username)` - Is there a way to JUST remove the (by username) part of the paragraph, so I'm left with only the photo title? If anyone could provide a script that'd be helpful!

Comment: @TheZ I didn't even know where to start - :contains is not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery:

```
$('p').html(function(){
   return $(this).text().replace(/\s+\(by\s+\w+\)/g, "");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/arEzS/

The above solution will replace the text within each paragraph element that matches the pattern of `(by [a-zA-Z0-9])`, where [a-zA-Z0-9] indicates any combination of alpha-numerical characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with regular expression:

```
$("p").html(function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(/\s+\(by\s+\w+\)$/, "");
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/GWyhM/

Answer (score 0):

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/QeZxn/11/

g = /g modifier makes sure that all occurrences of "replacement"

i = /i makes the regex match case insensitive

good read: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $foo = $('#content');

    $foo.html($foo.text().replace(/\(by Hulk\)/g,''));

});
```